# NestJS + Angular + Discord authentication

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, discord, nestjs

I'm working on a new project that will be a website for friends and me. I chose to use discord Oauth2 to handle the authentication of my website. My backend will be developped using NestJs, and the frontend will be based on angular as it's the framework I know the most.

I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGafqCNCCSs) to setup discord Oauth in my nestJs project, but now, I'm wondering how to link my nestJs session to my angular frontend, but didn't find anything on the subject. Maybe wrong keywords, but still didn't find. Any advice is welcome. Anyone has an idea ?

Trying to rephrase as asked in comment:

I currently have:

- An almost empty NestJs project for my website's backend. It is plugged to discord OAuth as guided in the video above
- An almost empty angular project for my website's frontend.

When logged to the api (nestjs) with discord, there is a session saved with user's info. I would like to get these info from my angular without having to log 2 times so the api can work transparently for the user once logged from the frontend

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SumitSharma I edited my question, I hope it's clear now, please tell me if it still is not

Comment: did you try out https://disco-oauth.vercel.app/ ? This was a lot easier for me

Comment: @RovelStars I didn't know it existed. Next time I'll work on my project I'll give it a look. Thanks